# Need help, can't see the mistake

Tags: sed, grep, cut, cat

My job is to follow a pipeline of different commands according to the specifications of a paper. However, there is a command with which chromosome names are to be changed. The command is so complicated that it is a real challenge for me.

```
$ cat < (head -50 Nipponbare_indel.vcf | grep ’#’ | sed ’s/ID=\([0-9][0-9]*\)/ID=Chr\1/g’ | cut -f1-8) < (grep -v ’#’ Nipponbare_indel.vcf | cut -f1-8 | sed ‘s/^\([0-9]*\)/Chr\1/g’) < (grep -v ’#’ NB_final_snp.vcf | cut -f1-8 | sed ’s/^\([0-9]*\)/Chr\1/g’) > Nipponbare_indel_SNP.vcf
```

output: 'Syntax error with the unexpected word ('

`echo $SHELL` gives `/bin/bash`

Does anyone see the mistake?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share samples of input and expected output in your question to make your question more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Bash has a special syntax (process substitution) `<(command)`, without a space between `<` and `(`.
Remove those spaces.
With some newlines:

```
cat <(head -50 Nipponbare_indel.vcf | grep ’#’ | 
      sed ’s/ID=\([0-9][0-9]*\)/ID=Chr\1/g’ | cut -f1-8) \
    <(grep -v ’#’ Nipponbare_indel.vcf | cut -f1-8 | 
      sed ‘s/^\([0-9]*\)/Chr\1/g’) \
    <(grep -v ’#’ NB_final_snp.vcf | cut -f1-8 | 
      sed ’s/^\([0-9]*\)/Chr\1/g’) > Nipponbare_indel_SNP.vcf
```

In the above command I did not repair the wrong single quotes.

In fact there is no need for using process substitution here, could just write

```
indel=Nipponbare_indel.vcf
snp=NB_final_snp.vcf
outfile=Nipponbare_indel_SNP.vcf

head -50 "${indel}" | grep ’#’ | 
   sed 's/ID=\([0-9][0-9]*\)/ID=Chr\1/g' | cut -f1-8 > "${outfile}"
grep -v '#' "${indel}" | cut -f1-8 | 
   sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)/Chr\1/g' >> "${outfile}"
grep -v '#' "${snp}" | cut -f1-8 | 
   sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)/Chr\1/g' >> "${outfile}"
```

Now you would like to remove repeating code, but it is unclear what you want without sample input and output files. In the original code "Chr" in included for all commented fields starting like `ID=(digits)`, the second and third `sed` are wrong:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)/Chr\1/g' inputfile
```

With `*` 0 or more mathes are allowed, resulting in inserting Chr for all not empty lines. The global flag `/g` has no effect, since `^` is matching the start of the line.
When you want to insert `Chr` before the first sequence of digits in the line, you can search for the first digit and use

```
indel=Nipponbare_indel.vcf
snp=NB_final_snp.vcf
tmpfile=NB_parsing.tmp
outfile=Nipponbare_indel_SNP.vcf

head -50 "${indel}" | grep ’#’ > "${tmpfile}"
grep -v '#' "${indel}" >> "${tmpfile}"
grep -v '#' "${snp}" >> "${tmpfile}"
cut -f1-8 "${tmpfile}" | sed 's/[0-9]/Chr&/' >> "${outfile}"
rm "${tmpfile}"
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, it's very clear and it works now :)